# compute path lengths of a graph, excluding intermediate sub-paths (igraph, R)

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I'm wondering if there is a way to compute path lengths from a graph or network, excluding paths between intermediate vertices (those with inbound *and* outbound edges). I'm working with the `igraph` R library (http://igraph.org/r/doc/), but other R solutions are also welcome.

So, given the following directed graph:

```
require(igraph)
edges= graph.formula(A -+ B,
                     A -+ C,
                     B -+ C,
                     C -+ D,
                     B -+ D,
                     D -+ E)
```

[image]

I aim to know the lengths of the following paths:

- A-B-C-D-E (4)
- A-B-D-E (3)
- A-C-D-E (3)

I can select my paths of interest with the following `igraph` function:

```
all_simple_paths(edges, from="A", to="E")
```

But to do that I need to know starts and ends of every subgraph beforehand, which is not easy in my real dataset: a large set of graphs as the one described above, say ~10,000 vertices organized in small, unconnected sets of up to ~10 vertices.

So, I'd need to be able to:

1. Identify all initial and final vertices of multiple subgraphs.
2. Get all possible paths between each pair of vertices
3. Get their lengths (something similar to what `path.length.hist` function does, but for the results of 2nd step).

These are different problems, but I thought the question is general enough to keep them in a single thread. As I said before, I like `igraph` but other R solutions are welcome too!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might work, although caution will be nedded if there are several connected components in the graph, and if there are no vertices that could play the role of "start" or "end" of the graph.

```
require(igraph)
edges <- graph.formula(A -+ B,
                     A -+ C,
                     B -+ C,
                     C -+ D,
                     B -+ D,
                     D -+ E)

indeg <- degree(edges, mode="in")
outdeg <- degree(edges, mode="out")
START <- names(indeg)[indeg==0] 
END <- names(outdeg)[outdeg==0]

listPaths <- NULL
for (start in START) {
  for (end in END) {
    listPaths <- append(listPaths, all_simple_paths(edges, from=start, to=end))
  }
}

lengthPaths <- sapply(listPaths, length)
```